# Custom adaptor with Radio button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating my own custom adapter. I have to put Radio button in front of every list item. I use this:

```
List<Address> result = myGeocoder.getFromLocationName(name,
                MAX_RESULT);


public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Address> {
    Context mycontext;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Address> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);            
        mycontext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int maxAddressLineIndex = getItem(position)
                .getMaxAddressLineIndex();
        String addressLine = "";
        for (int j = 0; j <= maxAddressLineIndex; j++) {
            addressLine += getItem(position).getAddressLine(j) + ",";
        }

        TextView rowAddress = new TextView(mycontext);
        rowAddress.setText(addressLine + "\n");

        return rowAddress;

    }
```

Can anybody tell how can I add Radio button.

Comment: Check the answer of this [Question][1]. Same as you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250599/android-listview-with-radiobutton-in-singlechoice-mode-and-a-custom-row-layout

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List<Address> result = myGeocoder.getFromLocationName(name,
            MAX_RESULT);
```

public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context mycontext;

```
public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Address> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);            
    mycontext = context;
}

    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int maxAddressLineIndex = getItem(position)
            .getMaxAddressLineIndex();
    String addressLine = "";
    for (int j = 0; j <= maxAddressLineIndex; j++) {
        addressLine += getItem(position).getAddressLine(j) + ",";
    }
    LinearLayout lyt = new LinearLayout(mycontext);
    TextView rowAddress = new TextView(mycontext);
    rowAddress.setText(addressLine + "\n");
    RadioButton rdo = new RadioButton(mycontext);

    lyt.addView(rowAddress);
    lyt.addView(rdo);
    return lyt;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you would to create a custom layout for list items,then use LayoutInflater in your getView() method.

> LayoutInflater Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding
>   View objects. It is never used directly. Instead, use
>   getLayoutInflater() or getSystemService(String) to retrieve a standard
>   LayoutInflater instance that is already hooked up to the current
>   context and correctly configured for the device you are running on.

A good example is [here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) and you can see fundamentals in it.A simple snippet is here:

```
…
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
…

@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listItem, null);
                …
            } else {
                …
            }
            …
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Reference:
[developer.android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)