# Using radio button in custom listview in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button

I have a custom listview which is done with getView. It must be 4 textview and a radiobutton on the right in each row. I saw many examples about this here but couldn't get the idea. Here is my getView function. With this situation i can see the rows but radiobuttons are still checked when i choose another radiobutton. What should i have to add to the function to make radiobuttons work properly and get Id of the selected one? Thanks

```
private static class CitizenAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
         private LayoutInflater mInflater;
         public CitizenAdapter(Context context) {
                   mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    }
         public int getCount() {
                    return sicilArr.size();
                    }
         public Object getItem(int position) {
                        return position;
                    }
         public long getItemId(int position) {
                        return position;
                    }       
         public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final ViewHolder holder;
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_citizen, null);
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                        holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
                        holder.text4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
                        holder.radioCitizen = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupCitizen);
                        holder.radioButCitizen  = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButtonCitizen);

                        holder.radioCitizen.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {                              
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                            }
                        });
                        convertView.setTag(holder);
                    } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    }       
                   holder.text1.setText(array1.get(position));
                   holder.text2.setText(array2.get(position));
                   holder.text3.setText(array3.get(position));  
                   holder.text4.setText(array4.get(position));


            return convertView;
           }        
             static class ViewHolder {      
                  TextView text1;
                  TextView text2;
                  TextView text3;
                  TextView text4;

                  RadioGroup radioCitizen;
                  RadioButton radioButCitizen;
                }       
            }
```

Also this is my xml row file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left|center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10px"
android:paddingTop="10px"
android:paddingLeft="3px">    
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#d08021">
 </TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#81A2BC">
 </TextView>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#81A2BC">
 </TextView>    
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#81A2BC">
 </TextView> 
 <RadioGroup 
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupCitizen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioButtonCitizen"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 7):

One way is to manually uncheck all others radiobuttons. You can create variable that will keep position of currently selected item. And in `getView` you check/uncheck current radio button depending on whether current position equals to selected one. When use press radio button you change position of selected item and call `notifyDatasetChanged`.
Also check this quesion: [Android ListView with RadioButton in singleChoice mode and a custom row layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250599/android-listview-with-radiobutton-in-singlechoice-mode-and-a-custom-row-layout)

1) Add `private int selected = -1` to `CitizenAdapter`.
2) Add click listener to each radiobutton:

```
holder.radioCitizen.setOnClickLisener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {                              
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(View view) {
            selected = (Integer) view.getTag();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

3) Set tag for each radiobutton to current position and set checked state:

```
// After you set text to 4 textviews
holder.radioButCitizen.setTag(position);
holder.radioButCitizen.setChecked(position == selected);
```

Comment: at the accepted answer on that link, there is again some explanation like this, can u specify some code? thanks

Comment: ok, found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter . But thanks anyway for your attention.

Comment: Thanks, thats the best solution. Your answer should be marked as *CHECKED*. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int selected = 0;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder holder;
    final RadioButton motif;

    if (null == convertView) 
    {
        convertView = View
                .inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.motif_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    motif = (RadioButton) holder.getmotif();

    motif.setTag(position);

    motif.setText(motifList.get(position));

    if(position == 0)
    {
        motif.setChecked(true);
    }
    else
        motif.setChecked(false);

    motif.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selected = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    if(position == selected)
        motif.setChecked(true);
    else
        motif.setChecked(false);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    private View mRow;
    private RadioButton motif = null;

    public ViewHolder(View row) {
        mRow = row;
    }

    public RadioButton getmotif() {
        if (motif == null) {
            motif = (RadioButton) mRow.findViewById(R.id.itemMotif);
        }
        return motif;
    }
}
```